# Adding a class to current slide using Slick Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

I have a small problem with Slick slider that I'm hoping to resolve.

What I'd like to be able to do is add a class to the current slide once it becomes active. This would include the first slide too when the slider loads. Once the slider moves onto the next slide, the class would be added after the slide has animated.

I suppose it would be more like a class toggle rather than just adding a class.

```
$('.latest-slider').slick({
infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 1,
speed:800,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: false,
arrows:false,
centerMode: true,
}); 

// On after slide change
$('.latest-slider > .slick-slide').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
$(this).toggleClass('active-class');
});
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone offer any advice on this?

EDIT

```
$('.latest-slider .slick-slide').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $(currentSlide).removeClass('fancy-class');
  $(nextSlide).addClass('fancy-class');
  //console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slick slider has a beforeChange callback for this purpose.

```
<div class="your-class">
    <div>
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2402987/467823860/stock-photo-table-with-food-top-view-467823860.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--U4p7aVXr--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/cqjqqduljubkqkglhgrz.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-d0Umq4tB7JWvT6U3JmqKBmyqCwtSokJTKM9eor38ITZUyoP8OA">
    </div>
</div>

$('.your-class').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $(".your-class").find('div').removeClass("current-slide");
    $(".your-class").find('div').eq(nextSlide).addClass("current-slide");
});
```

Comment: So going by the your example above, would my revised version be any closer? It still doesn't seem to be adding the class.

Comment: $('.latest-slider .slick-slide') should instead be $('.latest-slider')

Comment: It's strange. I just cannot seem to add the class. I can see that the console is logging the nextSlide. But can't figure out why it wouldn't be adding the class after the animation. Should I expect the class addition and removal to be on the .slick-slide? Thanks for your help, by the way

Comment: Updated response, adds class *current-slide* to the active slide.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution.

```js
$('.latest-slider .slick-slide').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).removeClass('active-slide');
  $(slick.$slides[nextSlide]).addClass('active-slide');
});
```